# Following a train of thought

Tags: verbs, phrases

I was listening to an English conversation yesterday and had a question. The speaker was having a conversation, and then suddenly made a comment that didn't seem to relate to the previous topic.

I wanted to say, "I can't follow her train of thought" or "that conversation doesn't seem to follow any train of thought.

I know that train of thought is 思考回路　but what very would you use for "follow"?  Not 従う right?

Comment: Despite being overly literal in your translation attempt (trying to translate an idiom instead of the base meaning it is meant to convey), a 'train of thought' is normally understood to be one individual's sequence of ruminations, not the flow of a conversation. 'I don't understand her use of that apparent non-sequitur.' might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think「付{つ}いて行{い}く」might be the word you're looking for.

> 彼女の話に**ついていけない**

- It's hard to follow what she's saying

> 話し方に**ついていく**のが難しい

- (Her) way of speaking is hard to follow